# When I click a link, click a link on another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Really struggling to think of a solution to this problem. I have thought anchor links might help (using the #example on the end of a link to scroll to a position on the page) but not sure how best to implement them.

So on the homepage of my site I have a list of links, that correlate to tabs on another page.

The links on the homepage:
(What is e-Bate, What are rebates etc.)
[Links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKEUg.png)

When you click one of the tabs on the other page, it activates a script which shows a certain div below:
[Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Hwd.png)

This is how the tabs are shown:

HTML:

```
<div class="page-links">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="whatebate">What is e-Bate?</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="whatrebate">What are rebates?</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="ebatefeat">e-Bate features</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="howebate">How e-Bate works</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="casestud">Case studies</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="page-contents">
<div id="whatebate" class="hideshowdiv">
<?php echo CFS()->get('whatisebate'); ?>
</div>
<div id="whatrebate" class="hideshowdiv">
<?php echo CFS()->get('what_are_rebates'); ?>
</div>
<div id="ebatefeat" class="hideshowdiv">
<?php echo CFS()->get('e_bate_features'); ?>
</div>
<div id="howebate" class="hideshowdiv">
<?php echo CFS()->get('how_e_bate_works'); ?>
</div>
<div id="casestud" class="hideshowdiv">
<?php echo CFS()->get('case_studies'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".page-contents div.hideshowdiv").hide();
      // Show chosen div, and hide all others
    jQuery("a").click(function (e) 
    {
        //e.preventDefault();
        jQuery("#" + jQuery(this).attr("class")).fadeIn().siblings('div.hideshowdiv').hide();
    });
    });
```

So when one of the links is clicked on the homepage, for instance, the 'What is e-Bate?' link, I want it to go to the other page, and click the corresponding tab, showing the content for that section. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to have browser to browser communications and the only way to do that would be with websockets.

Comment: Did you see this: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_menu_list-inline&stacked=h

Comment: @Avishake what relevance does that have? Also, friends don't let friends use W3Schools

Comment: In the example of the URL, there is an example of tabular view.

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible and you had half the equation with the anchors. Now you just need to write a small function to parse out the URL and check for a certain tag.

So something like this:

```
  $(function(){
      if (location.href.indexOf("#example") != -1) {
            //This is where you put your function to show the tab   
        }
      if (location.href.indexOf("#anotherexample") != -1) {
            //This is where you put your function to show the tab
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can use PHP, then it is indeed pretty easy:

First, you need to create a PHP file, *obvious* with an input parameter, preference, two `GET` variables, the first one being the link of the page you want to visit and the second one can be, well that depends on how you want it to be, it can be a div id, or a div class or pretty much id of anything you want to click on the second site (You MUST KNOW which button/link you want to click on the second site)

Then first in your php code, store these two things into variables, Let us take `$Path` and `$DivToClick`,

Now, use this PHP function:

```
file_get_contents(path,include_path,context,start,max_length)
```

Here, the path is an required field, rest is all optional.. and then after that, echo a JQuery code which will do something like this

```
function ClickTheButton ()
{
 $('#divId').click ();
}
```

Now, let me explain what we are doing here... First, you are sending link to a php script that get all the contents of that webpage and display it on my screen, and then when you are echo-ing the JQuery code, you are telling browser, that yes, this is the part of the page, execute it and simulate the action of click on this page, and thus the click action is simulated and things are done as per your need...

Hope this helps... :)